# New Game Button Causes Java Game Application To Stop Responding

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm making a java poker application using javaFX. I'm relatively new to java and javaFX in particular. I don't seem to be getting any explicit errors when my code compiles but when I run the program and click button "New Game" button, my application stops responding and I have no clue as to why.

The Opponent class is an abstract interface and inside this class there are four classes that describe the type of opponents.

The Opponent class is declared as:

```
public abstract interface Opponent
```

and one type of opponent is written as:

```
public static class tightAggressiveOpponent extends Player
        implements Opponent
```

I have tried to resolve this issue before posting my question. I would be grateful if anyone could offer any suggestions? The code for the actual button itself is:

```
public void handleNewGameButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
       run();
    }

public void run()
    {
        this.gameInfoText.set("Run method called");
        Table table = new Table();
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        Pot pot = new Pot();

        player1 = new Player("Oliver", false, pot, Boolean.valueOf(true));
        Opponent.tightAggressiveOpponent opponent = new Opponent.tightAggressiveOpponent("Jeremy (TA)", true, pot, table);
        player1.setOpponentPlayStyle(opponent.getPlayStyle());
        opponent.setOpponent(player1);

        playGame(player1, opponent, table, deck, pot);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an infinite loop or a blocking operation inside the method `playGame`.

You should run such method in a background thread. For example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        playGame(player1, opponent, table, deck, pot);
    }
}).start();
```

Also you cannot/should not update UI from a background thread. So use code like below inside the playGame method to update UI:

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        textArea.setText("something");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank for for your reply, Nabin. Would that suggestion replace the original run method entirely? I haven't used the Thread class before.

Comment: You can place the original run method as it is. Just replace the last statement of your code by the upper code block from my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that this code is found in the fxml Controller class.

Comment: So what? just do it.

Comment: The last part is giving an error when I put it in.

player1 = new Player("Oliver", false, pot, Boolean.valueOf(true));
        Opponent.tightAggressiveOpponent opponent = new Opponent.tightAggressiveOpponent("Jeremy (TA)", true, pot, table);
        player1.setOpponentPlayStyle(opponent.getPlayStyle());
        opponent.setOpponent(player1);

        new Thread(new Runnable(
    public void run(){
        playGame(player1, opponent, table, deck, pot);
    }
)).start();
    }

Comment: I'm sorry that looks like jargon but I can't seem to post code in this comment section.

Comment: Sorry I messed up braces earlier. check edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that has stopped int from crashing. I'm getting thread exceptions when I click the button but I will look into that. You've been really helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)